# SharePoint sites displaying "TLS Security Settings" error

Tags: error, site-collection, sharepoint-on-prem, browser-compatibility, tls

I have a SP2013 on-prem Farm with 3 web applications and multiple site collections

All the site collections in the farm display the below error:

**""Cant connect securely to this page"
This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening try contacting the website's owner."**

Also this error is displayed for all the users.

What could be the issue and how to make the site working?

Comment: Did you verify that the SSL Cert for the site is not expired and is valid?  Also verify that TLS is enabled in the registry, or by using iiscrypto.

Comment: Assuming that your farm was working successfully for some time before you suddenly started getting these errors, an expire SSL cert in IIS is most likely the cause.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMcClanahan after updating SSL certificates ,sites started working fine

Comment: Thanks @willman after updating SSL certificates ,sites started working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL certificates for the SharePoint URLs have got expired and after updating the new certificate, sites are working fine now.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer so future users searching for the same problem can find your resolved question.